# Android: Sqlite Exception no such table?

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

I have decided that I hate SQL and for that purpose I am trying to make a helper class that I can reuse over and over and never have to mess with it again but it isnt working!

Here is what I have right now:

DBAssistant.java

```
    public class DBAssistant {
            SQLiteDatabase db = null;


        public DBAssistant (){      
        }

        /** Opens database **/
        public void openDB(Context context, String name){
            db = new DBOpenHelper(context, name, DB_VERSION);
        }

        /** Creates the table "tableName" with the columns contained in "cols" **/
        public void createTable(String tableName, String[] cols){
            String table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + " (";
            int numOfColums = cols.length;
            columnNames = cols;
            for (int i = 0; i < (numOfColums - 1); i++){
                table += cols[i] + " VARCHAR, ";
            }
            table += cols[numOfColums - 1] + " VARCHAR);";
            try{
            db.execSQL("" + table);
            System.out.println("ExecSQL:" + table);
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.println("Column names: ");
            for (String c : getColNames(tableName)){
                System.out.print(c + " ");
            }
        }

        /** Inserts "data" into new row **/
        public void insertRow(String tableName, String[] data){
            int cols = getCols(tableName);

            System.out.println("if ((data.length) = " + (data.length) + ") ==" +
                    " (getCols(tableName) = " +  getCols(tableName) + ")?");
            if (data.length == cols){
                System.out.println("Inside if loop");
                String cmd = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (";
                for (int i = 0; i < cols - 1; i++){
                    cmd += getColNames(tableName)[i] + ", ";
                }
                cmd += getColNames(tableName)[cols - 1] + ") VALUES ('";
                for (int k = 0; k < data.length - 1; k++){
                    cmd += data[k] + "', '";
                }
                cmd += "');";
                System.out.println(cmd);
                db.execSQL(cmd);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Inside else loop");
                String dat = "";
                String sCols = "";
                for (String d : data)
                    dat += "'" + d + "'";
                for (String c : getColNames(tableName))
                    sCols += "'" + c + "'";
                System.out.println("-------------------");
                System.out.println("[insertRow] ERROR: Number of elements in data[" + dat + "]");
                System.out.println("doesnt match the number of columns [" + cols + "] in " + tableName);
                System.out.println("-------------------");
            }           
        }

        /** Return String[] containing the column names in tableName **/
        public String[] getColNames(String tableName){
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName , null);
            return c.getColumnNames();
        }

        /** Returns the number of rows in tableName **/
        public int getCols(String tableName){
            return getColNames(tableName).length;
        }

    /***  Other methods that have no relevance here .... ***/

private static class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DBOpenHelper(Context context, String dbName, int dbVersion) {
       super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // Do Nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // Do Nothing
    }
 }
}
```

I have included several System.out.println() statements to help me debug the code and find problems so please ignore them. PrintDB is another test that I wrote that I am using to make sure everything is working. Now this is what I have written to make sure everything is working....

```
DBAssistant db = new DBAssistant();
String dbName = "testing";
String tableName = "test";
String[] cols = {"_num", "num_eng", "num_span"};
String[] row1 = {"1", "one", "uno"};
String[] row2 = {"2", "two", "dos"};
String[] row3 = {"3", "three", "tres"};
String[] row4 = {"4", "four", "quatro"};
String[] row5 = {"5", "five", "cinco"};
TextView databaseView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.databaseView);

db.openDB(this, dbName);
db.createTable(tableName, cols);
db.insertRow(tableName, row1);
db.insertRow(tableName, row2);
db.insertRow(tableName, row3);
db.insertRow(tableName, row4);
db.insertRow(tableName, row5);
databaseView.setText(db.printTable(tableName));
```

Running this code everything goes great and all the System.out.println() statements have the right information in them until it gets to the `databaseView.setText(db.printTable(tableName));`
part and it throws an exception

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3440): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: test: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM test

Pointing to the line  in the `printTable()` method:

```
Cursor c = dbr.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName , null);
```

This has me so confused because that same line of code is used in the `getColNames()` method that was called several times before this and ran with no problem. Also if the table didn't exist wouldn't it have thrown an exception when I called `insertRow()`? I called that method 5 times in a row with not a single exception thrown! What is happening here?

Edit:

> Implement onCreate() in your DBOpenHelper. Put there content of the createTable() method.

Why would it be necessary to create the table in the `onCreate()` method? If I were to do this would I be able to use my existing method to do so and just call it from this method?

> And the second why you don't use content providers and uri >concept which is already SQLless?

Wha...? I have no idea. Please explain what that is or leave me a link to some sort of a tutorial.

Comment: If exception says that there is no table with such name then it;s true, have you checked it with adb console tool? And the second why you don't use content providers and uri concept which is already SQLless?

Comment: I got the same case too. Even if the name of the table is correct but still got an SQLException. (no such table)

Comment: AFAIK, content provider may not be required in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `onCreate()` in your `DBOpenHelper`. Put there content of the `createTable()` method.

See [Dev Guide](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

This exception can also raise because you query a column that does not exist. For instance, are you sure that your table has a col `_id` because android expects to find it.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening an error while creating Database. Just debug your code when you create the tables and if it is that you will see that there is an error